# Using GNU sort with multiple keys, text and numbers

Tags: shell, sort

I have some mail log excerpts that I'd like to sort first by e-mail address and then by date.

Example input data:

```
$ cat test3.txt
Oct 10 14:00:00 andy@example.com bounced
Oct 10 13:00:00 andy@example.com deferred
Oct 10 14:30:00 billy@example.com bounced
Oct 10 12:00:00 andy@example.com deferred
Oct 9 12:00:00 cindy@example.com deferred
Oct 9 14:00:00 cindy@example.com bounced
Oct 10 12:30:00 billy@example.com deferred
Oct 10 13:30:00 billy@example.com deferred
Oct 9 13:00:00 cindy@example.com deferred
```

The file in its current version is space delimited. So what I want is to sort first by the fourth column, and then by the first (as month), second (numerical) and third (numerical, I guess, unless the timestamps need special handling.) This is my best attempt:

```
$ sort -k 4,4 -k 1,1M -nk 2 test3.txt
Oct 9 12:00:00 cindy@example.com deferred
Oct 9 13:00:00 cindy@example.com deferred
Oct 9 14:00:00 cindy@example.com bounced
Oct 10 12:00:00 andy@example.com deferred
Oct 10 12:30:00 billy@example.com deferred
Oct 10 13:00:00 andy@example.com deferred
Oct 10 13:30:00 billy@example.com deferred
Oct 10 14:00:00 andy@example.com bounced
Oct 10 14:30:00 billy@example.com bounced
```

If I include only the "-k 4,4" key argument, it sorts fine according to the e-mail but that seems to get ignored when I add the other keys. For simplicity the first column can be ignored in this example; the problem is still there in that the sorting by the second column takes precedence over the fourth.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Whats your desired output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When in doubt, use `--debug` flag:

```
xb@dnxb:/tmp$ sort -k 4,4 -k 1,1M -nk 2 test3.txt --debug
sort: using ‘en_SG.UTF-8’ sorting rules
sort: key 3 is numeric and spans multiple fields
Oct 9 12:00:00 cindy@example.com deferred
               ^ no match for key
___
    _
_________________________________________
Oct 9 13:00:00 cindy@example.com deferred
               ^ no match for key
___
    _
_________________________________________
Oct 9 14:00:00 cindy@example.com bounced
               ^ no match for key
___
    _
________________________________________
```

This should works:

```
xb@dnxb:/tmp$ sort -b -k4,4 -k1M -k2n -k3n test3.txt --debug
sort: using ‘en_SG.UTF-8’ sorting rules
sort: key 3 is numeric and spans multiple fields
sort: key 4 is numeric and spans multiple fields
Oct 10 12:00:00 andy@example.com deferred
                ________________
___
    __
       __
_________________________________________
Oct 10 13:00:00 andy@example.com deferred
                ________________
___
    __
       __
_________________________________________

...

xb@dnxb:/tmp$ sort -b -k4,4 -k1M -k2n -k3n test3.txt
Oct 10 12:00:00 andy@example.com deferred
Oct 10 13:00:00 andy@example.com deferred
Oct 10 14:00:00 andy@example.com bounced
Oct 10 12:30:00 billy@example.com deferred
Oct 10 13:30:00 billy@example.com deferred
Oct 10 14:30:00 billy@example.com bounced
Oct 9 12:00:00 cindy@example.com deferred
Oct 9 13:00:00 cindy@example.com deferred
Oct 9 14:00:00 cindy@example.com bounced
xb@dnxb:/tmp$
```

Your `-nk 2` are wrong, as `info sort` stated:

```
A position in a sort field specified with ‘-k’ may have any of the
option letters ‘MbdfghinRrV’ appended to it, in which case no global
ordering options are inherited by that particular field.
```

So **option letters** `n` should append to `k` and its **position**. The order matters.

Comment: Thanks a lot, appending the **n** option to the second key argument, instead of prepending it, did indeed resolve my problem, so this is the correct answer. 

I neglected to mention versions; this is on a RHEL 6 system with sort 8.4, which unfortunately doesn't have the **--debug** option. I had studied the man page without finding the answer, but not the info page, which is quite a bit more informative. I will try to remember that in the future.